# Bash script to ban IPs from access file

Tags: bash, iptables

I am writing a bash script to collect IPs from apache2 access.log file, store them in an array and then check if these IPs exist in the iptable or not to ban them.

I resume that the Ban is not going well, due to IPs are not collected well:

```
 #/bin/bash/

BADWORDS=( '/etc/passwd' 'file' 'w00tw00t' 'fckeditor' 'ifconfig' )
# Store IPs
storeIPs=()
entries=${#BADWORDS[@]}

elements=$(($entries - 1))

for ((i=0; i<=$elements; i++))
do
setBadWord=${BADWORDS[$i]}

ch=$( cat /var/log/apache2/access.log | awk -F\" ' { print $1,$2 } ' | grep "$setBadWords" )
echo $ch >> spam.log

getIPs=$( cat spam.log | awk '{print $1}' )
echo "IP is $getIPs"

# Check if IP exists in he array
FOUND=`echo ${storeIPs[*]} | grep "$getIPs"`
returnElems=$?

if [ $returnElems  == "0" ]
then
echo "$getIPs exists"
else
echo "$getIPs NOT exists"
    storeIPs+=($getIPs)
fi

countIPs=${#storeIPs[@]}
echo "count stored $countIPs"

if [[ "$countIPs" -gt "0" ]]
then
    echo "Yes"
    chkIP=$( iptables -L --line | grep "$getIPs" )
    ipExists=$?

    if [[ $ipExists == "0" ]]
        then
iptables -I INPUT -s "$getIPs" -j DROP
    fi # end if [[ $ipExists == "0" ]]

fi # end if [[ "$countIPs" -gt "0" ]]

done # end for
```

Thank you very much

Comment: So you are basically replicating `fail2ban` job? `Thank you very much` - for what? What is your question? Is this script working? `if [[ $ipExists == "0" ]]` - there is a iptables command for checking if a rule exists in the chain. But better interest yourself in some firewall solution like `firewalld` or `ufd` or I use `shorewall` and let other tools handle the hard `iptables` work. `not collected well` - what does that mean? What it means to "not well" collect something? Please post sample input file and specify what do you expect should happen and what does or doesn't happen.

Comment: I think the problem is coming from storing the IPs in the array, the ban does not go well, it inserts IPs duplicated

Comment: `ban does not go well` "not well" is very vague. [Check if the rule already exists in the chain](https://superuser.com/questions/360094/how-can-i-check-if-an-iptables-rule-already-exists).  `if ! iptables -C INPUT -s "$getIPs" -j DROP; then iptables -I INPUT -s "$getIPs" -j DROP; fi`. But it would be way better to use `ipset` for easier management anyway. The dots in ip addresses are parsed by `grep "$getIPs"` as regex. Use `-F` with `grep` to match exact and turn off regex matching

Comment: I've got it, once I ban the IP "111.222.333.444", I checked the iptables and found banned like this "ec2-111.222.333.444.compute-1.amazonaws.com", is there any explantations?

Comment: Please read [man iptables](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) and `-n` option.

Comment: I banned the IPs then use `iptables-save | uniq | iptables-restore` to delete duplicated entries, thanks @KamilCuk

Comment: @KamilCuk: Last thing I want to know, can I use `tail -f` instead of `cat` to realtime monitor my log?

Comment: Sure. `access.log` most probably get's rotated, and you would want line buffering, so manipulate with `stdbuf -oL tail -F`

Comment: I used this command, hope it works nice: `tail -F /var/log/apache2/access.log | grep --line-buffered "/etc/passwd" | awk '{ print $1,$2,$3 }'`